# Wrong result when casting query in WCF Windows Phone

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

Basically when I try to move my queries result into a usable format, I get given outputs such as "systems.collections.whatever"

Instead I want the actual number returned.
this is how I select the value I want

```
 listBox2.DisplayMemberPath = "MonthlyHourLimit";
            listBox2.ItemsSource = e.Result;
            if (this.listBox2.Items.Count > 0)
                this.listBox2.SelectedIndex = 0;
            limit = listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

I should get "156" but instead I get "Timesheet_System.userDataService.UserData""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ListBox.SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem.aspx) is of type `object`, and the `ToString()` of any object is the type name.

To get the actual string value, you need to cast `listBox2.SelectedItem` to your data type first.

I'm assuming your `SelectedItem` is of type `UserData` based on the name it's giving you with `.ToString()`, so use something like this:

```
((UserData)listBox2.SelectedItem).ToString();
```

Or if you want `limit` to equal the `DisplayMemberPath`

```
((UserData)listBox2.SelectedItem).MonthlyHourLimit;
```

Comment: Hmm I get null when I try that. It's from a WCF query and to view it i had to use a data template. I dont know if that effects anything.

Comment: I'm not sure ( I'm new to this) I'd say it's a member of type " Userdata" as thats the database that the query has called from. ( e in the example is  from the data service method)
but it doesn't like
limit = listBox2.SelectedItem as string;
                var s = ((UserData)listBox2.SelectedItem).ToString();

Comment: Oh my god. You're the best !  I knew it'd be something simple.